How do I split parts of a long string that's a single line into many objects?
I'm trying to play around with some data from a game using Python.
The data I want and I'm pulling are coming from a long .lua file and are all in one single line. I want to break up this long line that's containing data into segments/make a table or json of the data contained in that line.
I tried to google a bit but the results I found were just splitting up "short blablabla sentences with a \n " new line indicator manualy added. That's not what I need here, I need a way to split parts of my one big line of data into single objects that I can work with.
The line is starting like this and the example contains the first 4 sets of data I want to pull out:
[start of line]select(2, ...).LoadData("AUCTIONDB_REALM_DATA","Lakeshire-Alliance",[[return {downloadTime=1718680714,fields={"itemString","minBuyout","numAuctions","marketValueRecent"},data={{41444,2NSF,4,2SOM},{52106,2UN5,L,2UN5},{8188,1534,6,1534},{12013,NAHJ,3,NAHJ},[even more data]
The data I want to work with are starting after
data={
each of the objects following are within a new pair of {} containing 4 different values.
After the last object the line is closing with
}}]]) --<AUCTIONDB_REALM_DATA,Lakeshire-Alliance,1718680714>
Pastebin to the full line: https://pastebin.com/XpJZuznk

Read a tutorial on string manipulation? [ask] and [mre]

Are you familiar with the re module?

This is a good case for the re module where you define the pattern of the data you're interested in and let re do all the hard work.
For example:
import re
from pathlib import Path

P = re.compile(r"\{(\w+,\w+,\w+,\w+)\}", re.A)

with Path("~/Downloads/XpJZuznk.txt").expanduser().open(mode="r") as fd:
    for e in P.findall(fd.read()):
        print(e)

This reveals 7,590 objects. Here's the tail of the output from this code:
4832,2D7J3U,1,2D7J3U
1405,0,1,0
2912,28L4J,1,28L4J
24637,EAU9,1,EAU9
25163,GUNQ,1,GUNQ
2883,0,1,0
14457,20JL8,1,20JL8
25220,1NTRCG,1,1NTRCG
14258,1QFR,1,1QFR
9936,B27N,1,B27N
10377,1OJ04,2,1OJ04
8301,1P328,1,1P328
31276,B4IUN,1,B4IUN
25291,16V5V,1,16V5V
36181,QM4L,1,QM4L
15324,N1BU,2,N1BU

